# .preventDefault() no funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

Estoy creando una tienda online como proyecto escolar en `Laravel`. Todo va bien hasta que quiero evitar que un botón ejecute su acción `submit`.

Ese es el código del formulario al que quiero condicionar con `AJAX`:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => '/in_cursos_carts', 'method' => 'POST', 'class' => "addtocart inline-block" ]) !!}
<input type="hidden" name="curso_id" value="{{$curso->id}}">
<input type="submit" value="Agregar al carrito" class="btn btn-info">
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Y este es el código `AJAX` que quiero ejecutar en el `submit` del formulario:

```
$('.addtocart').on("submit", function(ev) { 
    ev.preventDefault();

    var $form = $(this);
    var $button = $form.find("[type='submit']");

    $.ajax({
        url: $form.attr("action"),
        method: $form.attr("method"),
        data: $form.serialize(),
        beforeSend: function() {
            $button.val("Cargando...");
        },
        success: function() {
            $button.css("background-color", "#00c853").val("Agregado"); 
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log(err);
            $button.css("background-color", "d50000").val("Hubo un error.");
            setTimeout(function() {
                restartButton($button);
            }, 5000);
        },
    });

    return false;

});


function restartButton($button) {
    $button.val("Agregar al Carrito").attr("style", "");
};
```

La idea es que desde la vista donde aparecen los productos el usuario pueda agregar el producto al carrito de compras sin tener que ir a la pantalla donde va a pagar pero al parecer el `ev.preventDefault();` no está ejecutándose.

Comment: Intenta prevenir el `form` de los siguientes eventos: [**preventDefault()**](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/), [**stopPropagation()**](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/), y [**stopImmediatePropagation()**](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/)

Comment: ¿Cuál es el motivo por el que piensas que no se ejecuta el `preventDefault()`? ¿Se manda el formulario? ¿Se llega a ejecutar la función del evento? ¿Dónde pones ese código javascript? ¿Te sale algún mensaje de error en la consola de depuración de JavaScript? ¿Estás usando algún JavaScript para validar el formulario?

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias soluciones posibles con *Vainilla JS* para capturar y detener el evento.

Ejemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        .both-auto {
            margin-left : auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
        .flex {
            display: flex;
        }
        .flex-both {
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
        .flex-col {
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        .top-2 {
            margin-top: 2%;
        }
        .w-50 {
            width: 50%;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function log() // void
        {
            console.log(...arguments);
        }
        function qs(selector, node = null) // void
        {
            return (node || document).querySelector(selector);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="xxx.html" class="flex flex-col w-50 both-auto">
        <input type="text" class="top-2" name="name" placeholder="Nombre">
        <input type="email" class="top-2" name="email" placeholder="Email">
        <textarea name="message" class="top-2" rows="7" placeholder='Mensaje'></textarea>

        <div class="flex flex-both top-2">
            <button type="submit"
                className="btn btn-primary">
                Enviar (submit)
            </button>
            <button type="button"
                className="btn btn-primary">
                Enviar (button)
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script>
        const buttonButton = qs('button[type="button"]');
        const buttonSubmit = qs('button[type="submit"]');
        const form = qs('form');

        form.onsubmit = (ev) => {
            ev.preventDefault();
            log('form => submit event');
        }
        
        buttonSubmit.onclick = (ev) => {
            ev.preventDefault();
            log('button type submit => onclick event');
        }
        buttonSubmit.onsubmit = (ev) => {
            ev.preventDefault();
            log('button type submit => submit event');
        }
        buttonButton.onclick = (ev) => {
            ev.preventDefault();
            log('button type button => onclick event');
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Puedes validar datos o lo que necesites y al finalizar enviar el formulario con una sentencia como `document.querySelector('form').submit();`.

***Veamos el ejemplo:***

He añadido un botón de tipo *submit*, que es el habitual y desencadena el envío de formulario y otro de tipo *button*. Les asocio un evento de tipo `onclick` a cada uno, este será el primero que se ejecute al accionar los botones, por lo tanto no llegará al *submit* si se controla en este punto.

Como aclaración, en HTML5 a un botón, que quieras usar como tal (no para enviar un formulario concretamente), debe tener el tipo *button* para que no lance un *submit* por defecto. Entonces el botón de tipo *button* que puse sólo puede controlarse con un `onclick`, nunca enviaría por si mismo el formulario.

Si quitas el evento `onclick` del botón de *submit*, y dejas en evento `onsubmit` en el formulario y en el botón, el primer que se ejecuta es el del propio botón.

Entonces, ¿que para que controlar el evento en el propio formulario?
Es en el último punto en el que se ejecuta.
Para un formulario como éste, lo mejor sería controlar el evento en el formulario, por esta razón: si estas dentro de un `input` y se pulsa *enter* se lanza el `onsubmit`, entonces para el ejemplo dejaría sólo:

```
const form = qs('form');
form.onsubmit = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    log('form => submit event');
}
```

En este punto, un truco, para **evitar que pulsando *enter* se envíe el formulario**, justo después de la apertura del formulario, se puede añadir un botón de tipo *submit* deshabilitado y oculto, como este:

```
<button type="submit" style="display:none" disabled></button>
```

Esto funciona con o sin usar javascript, es decir al añadirlo solo activar el botón de tipo *submit* activaría el envío del formulario, ya se controle o no el evento, que ahora sí, se puede controlar en el botón o en el propio formulario. Entonces en ejemplo podría quedar:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        .both-auto {
            margin-left : auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
        .flex {
            display: flex;
        }
        .flex-both {
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
        .flex-col {
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        .top-2 {
            margin-top: 2%;
        }
        .w-50 {
            width: 50%;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function log() // void
        {
            console.log(...arguments);
        }
        function qs(selector, node = null) // void
        {
            return (node || document).querySelector(selector);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="xxx.html" class="flex flex-col w-50 both-auto">
        <button type="submit" style="display:none" disabled></button>

        <input type="text" class="top-2" name="name" placeholder="Nombre">
        <input type="email" class="top-2" name="email" placeholder="Email">
        <textarea name="message" class="top-2" rows="7" placeholder='Mensaje'></textarea>

        <div class="flex flex-both top-2">
            <button type="submit"
                className="btn btn-primary">
                Enviar (submit)
            </button>
            <button type="button"
                className="btn btn-primary">
                Enviar (button)
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script>
        qs('button[type="submit"]').onsubmit = (ev) => {
            ev.preventDefault();
            log('button type submit => submit event');

            // TODO:
            // qs('form').submit();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

***Nota:** para simplificar le he añadido un `display:none` en línea al butón deshabilitado, este hack en principio funciona, es importante que este `disabled` y oculto al usuario claro. El ideal para mi es el siguiente:*

```
<button type="submit" disabled hidden aria-hidden="true"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si es un tema de versión de browser esto debería cubrir las diferentes alternativas para "preventDefault".

```
function(ev){
    var  event = ev | window.event;
    if(event.preventDefault){
        event.preventDefault();
    }else{
        event.returnValue = false;
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta agregando un id a tu botón, luego agrega tu funcióndentro del evento de jQuery ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#botonSubmit').on("click", function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```